# Check if element is visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I have tried multiple ways to do this now, I am 80% there but it's still not quite there.
I have sections of different sizes. And my navigation where I am trying to add an active class when I'm on the corresponding section, showing that it is active.

The code has a tendency to be buggy, inside nav-gallery, I have a masonry gallery, and slick slider I'm not sure if that affects it. But the active class has a tendency to stick on the gallery, in the navigation.
Each section is at least 100vh in height.

Per a suggestion from Cedric, I tried with [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).
But it has the same problem, at least in my implementation, it is buggy and gallery somehow is active even when not in the viewport.

```
  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1
  }
  let callback = (entries, observer) => {
      console.log("callback called");
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        console.log("set active for " + entry.target.id);
        let sectionId = entry.target.id;
        navItems.each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $("a[href='#" + sectionId + "']").addClass('active');
    });
  };

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

  pageSections.each(function () {
    let target = document.querySelector("#" + $(this).attr('id'));
    observer.observe(target);
  });
```

```js
const navItems = $(".navigation-item");
const pageSections = $(".section-page");

const elementIsInView = el => {
    const scroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset
    const boundsTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + scroll

    const viewport = {
        top: scroll,
        bottom: scroll + window.innerHeight,
    }

    const bounds = {
        top: boundsTop,
        bottom: boundsTop + el.clientHeight,
    }

    return ( bounds.bottom >= viewport.top && bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom ) 
        || ( bounds.top <= viewport.bottom && bounds.top >= viewport.top );
}
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        pageSections.each(function () {
            console.log("elements to check " + $(this).attr('id'))
            if(elementIsInView($(this)[0])){
                console.log("element is in viewport " + $(this).attr('id'))
                // this = the section that is visible
                let sectionId = $(this).attr('id');
                navItems.each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
                $("a[href='#" + sectionId + "']").addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```css
.section-page{
  height:100vh;
}
.navigation-fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
}
.navigation-fixed ul li a.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation-fixed">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#nav-contact" class="navigation-item">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#nav-info" class="navigation-item">INFO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#nav-gallery" class="naviation-item">GALLERY</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#nav-home" class="navigation-item active">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <section class="section-page" id="nav-gallery">Content here</section>
<section class="section-page" id="nav-info">Content here</section>
<section class="section-page" id="nav-contact">Content here</section>
```

Comment: [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) could be a good lead…

Comment: @CedricCholley that does look promising, but might be a bit above me to accomplish. But I will try.

Comment: @CedricCholley i tried to make an example, but i'm not able to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small / basic example using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)
I hope this will help

```js
// list of elements to be observed
const targets = document.getElementsByClassName('section-page')

const options = {
  root: null, // null means root is viewport
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.5 // trigger callback when 50% of the element is visible
}


function callback(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {

    if(entry.isIntersecting){
     document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
      const sectionId = entry.target.id; // identify which element is visible in the viewport at 50%
      document.querySelector(`[href="#${sectionId}"]`).classList.add('active');
      
    }
  });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

[...targets].forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  font-family: sans-serif; 
}

#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-item {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navigation-item.active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}


#sections {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.section-page {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.section-page:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.section-page:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.section-page:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.section-page:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-home" class="navigation-item active">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-gallery" class="navigation-item">GALLERY</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-info" class="navigation-item">INFO</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-contact" class="navigation-item">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="sections">
    <section class="section-page" id="nav-home">
      <div class="content">Home section</div>
    </section>
    <section class="section-page" id="nav-gallery">
      <div class="content">Gallery section</div>
    </section>
    <section class="section-page" id="nav-info">
      <div class="content">Info section</div>
    </section>
    <section class="section-page" id="nav-contact">
      <div class="content">Contact section</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Not sure what to do about [...targets] says foreach is not a function.

Comment: i removed the ... from targets, so it didn't work, but then i put them back in and it worked :D What does ... do ?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('section-page')` returns an HTMLCollection when `forEach` is a method of the Array object. I used `...` [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the HTMLCollection in an Array. We could have used Array.from as well

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine with your code except for mispelling the class for GALLERY.  Once that's fixed it's no longer sticky.

In general, when you're willing to provide us with code like you have (thank you btw, it was very helpful) it'd be awesome if you could make one of StackOverflows special HTML+JS+CSS snippets.  It shows all the code the same way you have, but also allows for that code to be run and instantly copied to an answer where it can be edited a bit.  I've used such a snippet for my answer:

```js
const navItems = $(".navigation-item");
const pageSections = $(".section-page");

const elementIsInView = el => {
    const scroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset
    const boundsTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + scroll

    const viewport = {
        top: scroll,
        bottom: scroll + window.innerHeight,
    }

    const bounds = {
        top: boundsTop,
        bottom: boundsTop + el.clientHeight,
    }

    return ( bounds.bottom >= viewport.top && bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom ) 
        || ( bounds.top <= viewport.bottom && bounds.top >= viewport.top );
}
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        pageSections.each(function () {
            if(elementIsInView($(this)[0])){
                // this = the section that is visible
                let sectionId = $(this).attr('id');
                navItems.each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
                $("a[href='#" + sectionId + "']").addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```css
.section-page {
  height: 100vh;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}

.navigation-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navigation-fixed">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-contact" class="navigation-item">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-info" class="navigation-item">INFO</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-gallery" class="navigation-item">GALLERY</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-home" class="navigation-item active">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="section-page">Spacing</section>

<section class="section-page" id="nav-gallery">gallery here</section>
<section class="section-page">Spacing</section>

<section class="section-page" id="nav-info">info here</section>

<section class="section-page">Spacing</section>

<section class="section-page" id="nav-contact">contact here</section>
<section class="section-page">Spacing</section>
```

Comment: This has the same problem I have been having so far, that gallery keeps being active.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure?  I'm not seeing it as sticky at all in the demo included in my answer.